# How to improve numpy curve fitting

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I've got some data from a solar panel charger of time versus current that I'm trying to fit a curve to. The dataset (with times converted by matplotlib.dates.date2num) is at http://pastebin.com/4FAMbbCJ. I put the times into a list called Time and the current into Current.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fit = numpy.polyfit(Time, Current, 10)
fit_fxn = numpy.poly1d(fit)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot_date(Time, Current, '-r', xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title("Current flow over time")
plt.ylabel("milliAmps")
plt.xlabel("Time")

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot_date(Time, fit_fxn(Time), '-r', xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title("Current fxn with time")

plt.show()
```

The scatter plot comes out fine, but no matter how many coefficients I try with polyfit, I still get a generally straight line. EDIT: To my eyes the current rises and falls with a peak around noon as would be expected with solar power, but the curve puts maximum current at the earliest time and then falls on a straight line from there. I'd add an image but don't have enough reputation points. I think the error is much more likely in my implementation than in polyfit, I'm just looking to see where I screwed up.

Anyone have any ideas on how to find a better curve?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the polyfit routine doesn't work?  Mathematically you must define what you mean by a "better curve."  Why choose a polynomial as opposed to an exponential or a simple straight line?  Why a least-squares fit as opposed to some data smoothing algorithm?  No matter what function you use (polynomial or otherwise), any statistical method will give you the best fit to the data in a least-squares sense.

Comment: Your implementation looks fine, the problem is that your data doesn't look like a polynomial.  What is the goal of your fit?  Surely you aren't looking for some expected coefficients (since solar flux vs time is not really polynomial), maybe you just want a nice curve for plotting?  Maybe you're looking for the time or value of peak current?

Comment: It surely can be better than a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more a problem of the independent variable. You are using polynomial of degree 10 but that means that you will have something like 4.5e+58 -> your coefficients will have to be very small and you will lose precision.

Try shifting the time variable by its minimum this way.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = Time-Time.min()

fit = numpy.polyfit(t, Current, 10)
fit_fxn = numpy.poly1d(fit)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot_date(Time, Current, '-r', xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title("Current flow over time")
plt.ylabel("milliAmps")
plt.xlabel("Time")

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot_date(Time, fit_fxn(t), '-r', xdate=True, ydate=False)
plt.title("Current fxn with time")

plt.show()
```

Comment: t = Time-Time.min() gave an error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'" and t = Time-min(Time) gave "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'". However, running the list through `minimum = min(Time); for time in Time: t.append(time - minimum)` worked. Then it gave a great fit curve! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Since you use numpy's polyfit I just assumed that Time is a numpy array. If you convert your lists into arrays, it shouldn't give you any more problems.

Comment: Then again I should have warned you already - polynomials of higher degree are bad idea [see Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realise that if the number are too big the fit will not work properly. 
Try to rescale your units. That works for me.